# Calculating the witness size of a transaction

Tags: segregated-witness, witness-data

I want to calculate how many % of a block, and thus, transactions that are witness data. I need to calculate the size of the witness data in bytes in every transaction. And as I understand it, I cannot calculate this using existing size variables like vsize.

Will a loop through the "txinwitness" array of hex and do a byte length calculation on every one be enough? (Using NodeJS here)

```
Buffer.byteLength('03fbcc1c24903bc2fb1d73czef518b859232341c39e4515367653d80536d587b62d6', 'hex');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on Andrew's answer:

You can calculate it from `size` and `vsize`.

### Transaction size

[See BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#transaction-size-calculations)

> Transaction weight is defined as Base transaction size * 3 + Total
>   transaction size (ie. the same method as calculating Block weight from
>   Base size and Total size).
>
> Virtual transaction size is defined as Transaction weight / 4 (rounded
>   up to the next integer).
>
> Base transaction size is the size of the transaction serialised with
>   the witness data stripped.
>
> Total transaction size is the transaction size in bytes serialized as
>   described in BIP144, including base data and witness data.

### Witness size

So, for example if you have a transaction that has a total size of 1200 bytes (including witness data), and a base size of 1000 bytes, the weight and virtual size are:

`weight = 1000 bytes * 3 + 1200 bytes = 4200`
`vsize = 4200 / 4 = 1050 bytes`

So, given `size` and `vsize`, you can calculate the size of witness data:

`witness size = (4/3) * (total - vsize)`
`witness size = 200`

Answer (score 3):

> Will a loop through the "txinwitness" array of hex and do a byte length calculation on every one be enough?

That is not enough as there are extra data in witnesses that is not included in the `txinwitness`.

You can get the number of witness bytes and the number of non-witness bytes by solving a system of equations. The `getrawtransaction` RPC gives you two fields, `size` and `weight`. `size` is the total size in bytes as received over the wire. `weight` is the weight of the transaction as defined by BIP 141.

If you let `x` be the number of non-witness bytes, and `y` be the number of witness bytes, the definitions of `size` and `weight` gives you:

```
4x + 1y = weight
x + y = size
```

By plugging in the `weight` and `size` from the RPC, you can solve the system of equations for `x` and `y` to get the number of non-witness bytes and number of witness bytes respectively.

Comment: So x = (weight - size)/3, y = (4*size - weight)/3

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bitcoinjs-lib` like I do, after signing inputs for tx you extractTransaction and get the object:

```
import { Psbt } from 'bitcoinjs-lib';

const psbt = new Psbt(...)

const allInputs = psbt.finalizeAllInputs();
const extractedTx = allInputs.extractTransaction(increaseFeeRate, customFee);
```

extractedTx is of following format:

```
interface SignedTransaction {
  ins: SignedTxInput[],
  locktime: number,
  outs: SignedTxOutput[],
  version: number
}
```

`ins` here is of following format:

```
interface SignedTxInput {
  hash: Buffer,
  index: number,
  script: Buffer,
  sequence: number,
  witness: Buffer[],
}
```

Sum witness buffers for each input and you will have your witness weight.